# What do matchit.vim's [%, ]%, a% do?

Tags: cursor-movement, plugin-matchit

matchit's `%`/`g%` are simple enough to use, but I'm having trouble understanding the other mappings, which sound potentially useful but don't seem to work in any understandable way.

```
]%  Go to [count] next unmatched group, as specified by
    |b:match_words|.  Similar to |]}|.
```

I would expect this maybe to allow me to jump to `endif`, `endfunction`, etc.  Take the following vimscript example, using the built-in vim ftplugin (`b:match_words` appears to be set.)

```
function! SuperTab()
  let l:part = strpart(getline('.'),col('.')-2,1)
  if (l:part=~'^\W\?$')
      return "\<Tab>"
  else
      return "\<C-n>"
  endif
endfunction
```

`[%` most of the time jumps to the `function!`, occasionally (inconsistently depending on cursor position) jumps to the `if`, and totally ignores `(`s.  `]%` jumps to `)`s and nothing else.  `va%` behaves identically to `[%` in this example and does not select anything.  Is this normal behavior?  Is there some example where these mappings make sense?

Comment: Good question! I thought I'd enable it and come up with an answer but I'm as stumped as you. As far as I can see `]%` does almost nothing. I'm going to have to take a look at the code.

Comment: I think it might just be buggy. As far as I can tell from the documentation and comments in the code, it should work as you suggested. Possibly someone (@BLayer? Or maybe me!) will take a look at the actual code and tell you why/how it goes wrong.

Comment: I'll try to respond this weekend. I did a little poking some time back and am sure it's badly bugged but I didn't debug it in any depth.

Comment: I just tried neovim's matchit in vim (surprisingly is different than vim's) and it seems to work.. weird https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/plugin/matchit.vim

Comment: However, neovim's `va%`  `(((   )))` does not "expand" after repeated `a%`.  I'm not sure if vim's ever did, but imo it should.just like `a(`.

Comment: Well, looks like there's no need for me to dig in further. @user852573 has more than got it covered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you use the latest `matchit` plugin version [1.13.3](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/fc2b270cfd36230166df486aae4d96d9d1f32755/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim) which I could find at the moment on Vim's github repository.

> `[%` most of the time jumps to the `function!`, occasionally
>   (inconsistently depending on cursor position) jumps to the `if`, and
>   totally ignores `(`s.

When you hit `[%`, the `s:MultiMatch()` function is invoked. At the end of the latter, there's a `while` loop whose number of iterations is `v:count1`. This variable stores the count for the last normal command. Here, it should be `1`, because you didn't hit any number before `[%`. But in the middle of the function, some `:normal` commands are executed to save the screen and cursor position. These normal commands alter the value of `v:count1`.

You can check this like so:

```
nno cd :<c-u>call Func()<cr>
fu! Func()
    echom v:count1
endfu
```

Source this code, and press `cd`, read your messages (`:messages`): you should see `1`, because you didn't hit any number before `cd`.
Now, source this code:

```
nno cd :<c-u>call Func()<cr>
fu! Func()
    norm! 3G
    echom v:count1
endfu
```

And do the same experiment, press `cd` in a file with more than 3 lines. This time, in the messages, you should see `3`, not `1`.

Because of this, the `searchpair()` function inside the loop is invoked too many times, which, I suspect, explains the behavior you described. At least, it does on my machine (Linux, Vim `8.0` patches `1-134`).

To fix this, you could delete the [line 729](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/fc2b270cfd36230166df486aae4d96d9d1f32755/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim#L729):

```
let level = v:count1
```

And move it at the beginning of the function (before any other commands, including `:normal` commands, has the chance to alter `v:count1`):

```
fun! s:MultiMatch(spflag, mode)
  if !exists("b:match_words") || b:match_words == ""
    return ""
  end
  let level = v:count1
```

[image]

---

> I just tried neovim's matchit in vim (surprisingly is different than
>   vim's) and it seems to work.. weird

This is probably because of the [pull request #5124](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/5124) that neovim merged a year ago. According to the commit message, its purpose was to prevent `matchit` to add an undesired entry in the jumplist. To solve this, the commit changed how the screen and cursor positions were saved. It doesn't use `:normal` commands anymore, but invokes the function `winsaveview()` and `winrestview()`. By getting rid of `:normal`, for a different purpose, they've also fixed the issue you described earlier, because `v:count1` isn't modified anymore. Although it could be in the future if some commands are added in the middle of the function.

---

> `]%` jumps to `)`s and nothing else.

Towards the end of the `s:MultiMatch()` function, [line 722](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/fc2b270cfd36230166df486aae4d96d9d1f32755/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim#L722), the pattern describing the end part of a group of tokens is defined like this:

```
let closepat = substitute(closepat, ',', '\\|', 'g')
```

The purpose of the substitution is to replace each comma, which separates 2 consecutive groups of tokens, with a double escaped bar which will be interpreted by Vim's regex engine as an alternation (separation between 2 branches). I think that the substitution should also replace the colons `:` which separate the tokens inside each group. So, you could rewrite the substitution like this:

```
let closepat = substitute(closepat, '[,:]', '\\|', 'g')
```

With this change, `]%` should move the cursor on the various tokens described in `b:match_words` and `&l:matchpairs`, not just `)`. At least, it does on my machine.

[image]

---

> `va%` behaves identically to `[%` in this example and does not select
>   anything.

With the previous changes, in particular the 2nd one, `va%` should select the text between the 2 surrounding tokens. Although, the plugin seems to treat a middle part of a group of tokens (like `else` in `if|else|endif`) as an end part (it's passed to `searchpair()` through its 3rd argument, not its 2nd). So, what it considers to be the surrounding tokens may sometimes surprise you.

---

> However, neovim's `va%` `((( )))` does not "expand" after repeated `a%`. I'm
>   not sure if vim's ever did, but imo it should. just like `a(`.

Currently, the visual mapping `a%` is defined on [line 71](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/fc2b270cfd36230166df486aae4d96d9d1f32755/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim#L71) like this:

```
vmap a% <Esc>[%v]%
```

When I add `o` at the beginning of the `{rhs}`, to move the cursor to the beginning of the selection (`:h v_o`), I get the behavior that you want:

```
vmap a% o<Esc>[%v]%
```

[image]

---

Here's a [version](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lacygoill/315ecfcacb05278a651904e88be1464a/raw/67bb02354e177a52ba43365411a061ad297ded0c/matchit1.vim) of the `matchit` plugin, with the 3 small changes described so far.
And here's [another one](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lacygoill/f9c04c3cf869a71ecfe800b40a491251/raw/14573af104776b7c142d297067695e411ff60398/matchit2.vim) where I tried to also include the PR #5124 from Neovim.

If you want to test the code on your machine, but you don't have the rights to change the default `matchit` plugin (or you don't want to), you can create the file `~/.vim/plugin/matchit.vim`, and write your experimental `matchit` plugin there.

Since in the runtimepath, `~/.vim` comes before `$VIMRUNTIME`, Vim should source your custom version before the default one. And since, the default plugin has the guard:

```
if exists("loaded_matchit") || &cp
  finish
endif
let loaded_matchit = 1
```

... only your version should be fully sourced.

Comment: please open issues for the various problems you have fixed at https://github.com/chrisbra/matchit

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Ok, I've opened 2 issues to discuss the `]%` and `v_a%` mappings which could be changed a little.

Comment: Amazing answer!  I am a bit surprised at how apparently few people use these features, but I'm glad we can understand what's going on now.