# How to go to end/get out of the parenthesis of a line in vim?

Tags: cursor-movement

I read the solution answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037825/vim-get-out-of-parenthesis-brackets-etc. That is nothing but command `A` that takes away you in the end of line.

But, my requirement is something different. Suppose I have a file containing -
`x = (3+5)/(2+1);`
When cursor is on `+` I want to move the cursor on `/` or first `)`, but not on `;`(You can consider 'after the character' instead of 'on the character' ).

Comment: something like this: `nnoremap ,f /[)/]<cr>`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yes, something similar this. But, the parenthesis are may be different so I have to check whether I am in `()` or `{}` or `[]` or `<>`(although it is not parenthesis).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear if this is what you're asking, but I think you might be looking for:

```
])
```

This jumps to the nearest enclosing `)`. So if your cursor was on the `/` in the below:

```
(2 / (3 + 5) * 9) 
   ^
```

It would skip past the first `)` and jump to here:

```
(2 / (3 + 5) * 9)
                ^
```

Alternatively, for your more simple case, `%%` would also work. The first `%` jumps to the opening `(`, and the second jumps to its counterpart, the closing `)`.

See:

- `:help ])`
- `:help %`

Comment: `]}` `])` `[{` `[(` work but `[[` and `]]` don't work.

Comment: @alhelal `[[` and `]]` do something different: see `:h ]]`

Comment: What would you do to make it work with `]]`?

Answer (score 2):

My plugin [match-up](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup) provides the mappings `]%` and `[%` which is like a delimiter-agnostic version of `])`/`]}`  to go to either element of a surrounding matching pair.  Since it uses the symbols listed in `matchpairs`, it works for `()`/`{}`/`[]` by default and will work for `<` and `>` if `matchpairs` contains `<:>`.

Filetypes can also specify more advanced matching pairs (e.g., `if/endif` in vimscript), similar to the plugin matchit which is distributed with vim (except matchit seems to be unmaintained and these [mappings don't work](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13155/what-do-matchit-vims-a-do)).